# How to pass route values from autocomplete search to my URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need to get some help, I tried everything, to pass the route values to my URL but still I have the same problem. I want to get my route values from TextBox (movieTitle) and DropDownList (languageID). For TextBox I'm using also jquery autocomplete function. After clicking on the button I want to redirect the user to the new page with movie details. The problem is with my routing, because the details page looks like this, with only controller name and action name:

```
Movie/MyMovie
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
Movie/movieTitle-languageID
```

But in some reason my routing is ignoring the `searchTerm` (movieTitle) and `searchQ` (languageID)

Of course I tried to pass in `@using(Html.BeginForm())` the route values for `Model.Movie.MovieID` but it's throwing me an error and that's understandable. Have you guys any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Here is my action for autocomplete:

```
public JsonResult GetMovie(string term)
{
    List<string> movies;

    var viewModel = new ViewModel
    {
        Movies = db.Movies.Where(x => x.MovieTitle.StartsWith(term)).ToList(),
        Languages = db.Languages.ToList()
    };

    movies = db.Movies.Where(x => x.MovieTitle.StartsWith(term)).Select(y => y.MovieTitle).ToList();
    return Json(movies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("MyMovie", "Movie", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <b>Movie Title:</b>
                @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Language.LanguageId, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "LanguageId", "LanguageName", Model.Languages.First().LanguageId), new { Name = "searchQ" })
                <input type="submit" id="sss" value="Search" />
            }
```

Autocomplete:

```
$('#txtSearch').autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("GetMovie")'
});
```

And my action MyMovie:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMovie(string searchTerm, int searchQ)
{
    //string decodedGenre = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(searchTerm);

    var viewModel = new ViewModel
    {
        Movie = db.Movies.Where(x => x.MovieTitle == searchTerm).FirstOrDefault(),
        //Subtitles = db.Subtitles.Where((x => x.LanguageId == searchQ)
        Subtitles = db.Subtitles.Where(x => x.LanguageId == searchQ && x.MovieTitle == searchTerm)
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MyMovie",
        url: "Movie/MyMovie/{searchTerm}-{searchQ}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Movie", action = "MyMovie" },
        constraints: new { searchTerm = @"[\w& ]+" }
    );
```

I want also to get movieID to my action `MyMovie` and pass it to the URL but I really don't know how I can do this, because in my TextBox I'm passing only string `MovieTitle` . Thanks to this I could change the `MyMovie` action to search Movie by his ID, --- for example: `Movie = db.Movies.Find(id)`

Here is also my ViewModel maybe it will help you somehow.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Language> Languages { get; set; }

    public Subtitle Subtitle { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Subtitle> Subtitles { get; set; }

    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

**//Okay, small update. I changed the method from POST to GET and now my URL looks like this, but still can't get exactly what I want.**

```
Movie/MyMovie?searchTerm=Ant+Man&searchQ=1
```

Comment: Have you added your 'MyMovie' route before or after the default route?

Comment: It was before but even after nothing happens.

Comment: I see you are using jQuery autocomplete, do you expect the user to find a movie, select it using the textbox, select a language and THEN click on Search to navigate to the detail page of that Movie in that language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are submitting a form using GET, that will encode the form contents as querystring parameters ('17.13.1 Form submission method' at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13 for more details)

A way to achieve the desired result would be using JavaScript to construct a link to the desired url as shown below:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model StackOverflow_34576477.Models.ViewModel
<b>Movie Title:</b>
@Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Language.LanguageId, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "LanguageId", "LanguageName", Model.Languages.First().LanguageId), new { Name = "searchQ" })
<input type="button" id="sss" value="Search" />

<script>
    $('#txtSearch').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetMovie")'
    });
    //Submitting a form with GET will encode the form contents as querystring parameters (not the desired result).
    //Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13
    //Alternative (not necessarily most elegant) solution:
    $('#sss').click(function (parameters) {
        var targetUrl = '@Url.Action("MyMovie")';
        var movieTitle = $("#txtSearch").val();
        var selectedLanguageId = $("select[name='searchQ']").val();
        targetUrl += "/" + movieTitle + "-" + selectedLanguageId;
        window.location.href = targetUrl;
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, I have just one problem with this function. I'm using this search option as Partial View. It's in Home View and also in MyMovie View. The problem is with searching in MyMovie View, because when I click search Im getting url like this one: Movie/MyMovie/Batman/1/Batman/3. I tried to set movieTitle and selectedLanguageId to empty string but still the same result.